# Firebase LimitToLast crash when trying to load new data

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to load more elements after my 20 users are posted into my ListView ( this feature is working fine) but when I scroll to the bottom of the ListView I want to load another 20 users but it crashs.

This is what I have made so far

**FilterData.class**

```
private String oldestUserID;

private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    mList.clear();

    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

        oldestUserID = dataSnapshot.getKey();
        userPojo = snapshot.getValue(UserPojo.class);
        String email = userPojo.getEmail();
        mList.add(email);
    }
    fetchSuccessListener.onListFetched(true);
}

public void refillListView(ListView listView) {

    listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            currentScrollState = scrollState;
            isScrollCompleted();

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                             int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
            currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
            totalItem = totalItemCount;

        }

        private void isScrollCompleted() {
            if (totalItem - currentFirstVisibleItem == currentVisibleItemCount
                    && currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

                mDatabase.orderByKey().startAt(oldestUserID).limitToFirst(20).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        fetchData(dataSnapshot);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }


        }


    });
}
```

This is how it's working, I use an interface to detect when my data is done fetching and notify my adapter to populate the ListView, that is working fine with my first 20 users, but when I scroll till the end I want the list to add new  users (20 more) , but I got this crashlog

> Can't call limitToLast on query with previously set limit!

Now, here is how I call my methods in order to get the data

**MainActivity.class**

Interface to fill the listview when data is retrieved (working fine)

```
@Override
public void onListFetched(boolean fetched) {
    if(fetched){

        mUserListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

and this to just know when the user have scrolled and needs to load another 20 more users

```
filterData.refillListView(mUserListView);
```

What I'm trying to do above is to get the last userID in my database in order to start querying 20 new users after the last one queried , so I can load 20 more.

Here is the query I use to get the first 20 users

```
 mRootDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Usuarios");
        query = mRootDatabase.limitToFirst(20);
```

Firebase Database Structure looks like this

[image: Firebase Database]

Edit: Logcat error is pointing at this line

```
mDatabase.orderByKey().startAt(oldestUserID).limitToFirst(20).....
```

Thanks for any help !

Edit: snippet

```
public void refillListView() {
mQueryDatabase.orderByKey().startAt(oldestUserID).limitToFirst(20).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            fetchData(dataSnapshot);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
}
```

where `private Query mQueryDatabase;` is passed with my constructor

```
public FilterData(Query mQueryDatabase, Context context) {
        this.mQueryDatabase = mQueryDatabase;
        this.userPojo = new UserPojo();
        this.mContext = context;
    }
```

and filled like this

```
  Query query = mRootDatabase.limitToFirst(20);
       FilterData filterData  = new FilterData(query,this);
```

oldestUserID is fetched from `fetchData(dataSnapshot);`

Where fetchData is

```
private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        mList.clear();

        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            oldestUserID = snapshot.getKey();
            userPojo = snapshot.getValue(UserPojo.class);
            String email = userPojo.getEmail();
            mList.add(email);
        }
        fetchSuccessListener.onListFetched(true);
    }
```

Comment: That error is thrown when you call `limitToFirst()` and/or `limitToLast()` multiple times in a single query. I've never seen it thrown without that cause, so that would be my first suspicion. Can you reproduce the problem without the scrolling, so that I can see the problem in a single snippet that doesn't require any UI?

Comment: Btw: great job on implementing the concept of endless scroll correctly on Firebase Realtime Database. Most developers who are new to Firebase struggle considerably with this, since Firebase queries are not offset-based. :-)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot frank, I'm going to do it right now and let you know

Comment: this is what I get frank You must use startAt(String value), endAt(String value) or equalTo(String value) in combination with orderByKey(). Other type of values or using the version with 2 parameters is not supported

Comment: If you can reproduce in a single snippet that I can copy/paste I can have a look. Right now, I'm missing how `mDatabase` is initialized for example. By putting everything into a single self-contained piece of code, you make it easy for others to get the same problem on our screens, making it much easier to see what's going on. Such a so-called [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful) is really the best way to get help on code-related issues.

Comment: done frank, let me know if that's ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I see you do this initially:

```
Query query = mRootDatabase.limitToFirst(20);
FilterData filterData  = new FilterData(query,this);
```

And `FilterData` then does:

```
public FilterData(Query mQueryDatabase, Context context) {
    this.mQueryDatabase = mQueryDatabase;
    this.userPojo = new UserPojo();
    this.mContext = context;
}
```

And then:

```
mQueryDatabase.orderByKey().startAt(oldestUserID).limitToFirst(20).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        fetchData(dataSnapshot);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

At this point if we chain the things together, you have:

```
mRootDatabase
  .limitToFirst(20)
  .orderByKey()
  .startAt(oldestUserID)
  .limitToFirst(20)
  .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
    ...
```

And since you have `limitToFirst(20)` in there twice, it explains why you get an error message.

My gut feeling is that you want to pass the root reference for the query into `FilterData`, so:

```
FilterData filterData  = new FilterData(mRootDatabase,this);
```

---

Alternatively, you can build the base query (all the parts of the query that are constant) outside of `FilterData`:

```
Query query = mRootDatabase.orderByKey().limitToFirst(20);
```

And then in `FilterData` you only add the variable part (the `startAt()` clause):

```
mQueryDatabase.startAt(oldestUserID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        fetchData(dataSnapshot);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

Comment: Good to hear Todd. Note that this is precisely why we ask for a [single, self-contained MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which involves setting up a small new project/method that reproduces the problem. Often developers find the problem themselves while building an MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

Here I have done Firebase-Chat-Pagination. Check with this.It may help you.

```
private void loadDataFirst() {
    mUserRefValueEventListener = mConversationRef.child(mLocation)
            .limitToLast(TOTAL_ITEM_EACH_LOAD)
            .orderByKey()
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // It should be null when new meesage sent by own
                    mLastDataSnapshot = null;
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        mChatList.clear();
                        for (DataSnapshot readDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            ChatResponse chatModel = readDataSnapshot.getValue(ChatResponse.class);
                            if (chatModel != null) {
                                mChatList.add(chatModel);
                            }
                            // We need First DataSnapshot for pagination
                            if (mLastDataSnapshot == null) {
                                mLastDataSnapshot = readDataSnapshot;
                            }

                        }
                        mView.onFetchMessagesSuccess(mChatList);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

}

 public void loadMoreDataPagination() {

    if (mLastDataSnapshot != null && (mTotalCount == 0 || mView.getChatMessageCount() < mTotalCount)) {
        mUserRefValueEventListener = mConversationRef.child(mLocation)
                .orderByKey()
                .endAt(mLastDataSnapshot.getKey())
                .limitToLast(TOTAL_ITEM_EACH_LOAD)
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            mChatList.clear();
                            for (DataSnapshot readDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                ChatResponse chatModel = readDataSnapshot.getValue(ChatResponse.class);
                                if (chatModel != null) {
                                    mChatList.add(chatModel);
                                }
                                // We need Last DataSnapshot for pagination while load more
                                if (mChatList.size() == 1) {
                                    mLastDataSnapshot = readDataSnapshot;
                                }
                            }
                            // One item duplicates from last list so need to Remove it
                            mChatList.remove(mChatList.size() - 1);
                            mView.onFetchLoadMoreSuccess(mChatList, mTotalCount);

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        mView.hideLoading();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```